# How to display current tab name or Id of Visualforce page in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, onclick

In my application there is a VF page contains 5 tabs and each tabs performs different activities.There are 2 checkboxes present on the 2 different tabs.
I have created a onclick JS button which uncheck the checkboxes if the checkbox is already checked.
Now the problem that I am facing is when I unchecked it, it uncheck  all the checkboxes of  2 tabs but I want to perform this activity for current tab only.

I have the following code in  my VF which display the current tab name:

```
function displayPage() {
    var current = this.parentNode.getAttribute("data-current");
    if (current != null) {
                  document.getElementById("tabheader_" + current).removeAttribute("class");
        document.getElementById("tabpage_" + current).style.display="none";
    }
    var ident = this.id.split("_")[1];
            this.setAttribute("class","active");
    document.getElementById("tabpage_" + ident).style.display="block";
    this.parentNode.setAttribute("data-current",ident);
}
```

and I want to get the name/id of the tab in my apex class so that I can use in my IF condition.
Can someone help me how can I get the current tab name of VF in apex class?

> Note:When I click on a tab,i have to get the name of only those tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String tabId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdc.tabName');
```

This will get you tab Id of your current Visualforce Page Tab.

Comment: when I use the following syntax in my Apex class code then it gives me below error:                                                                                                    A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:{faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null objectClass.OpportunityController.checkboxFalse: line 47, column 1', }

Comment: Is you Apex class controller for your Visualforce Page or just a normal class with static methods?

Comment: its a controller class actually which contains info about every tabs.As I am adding custom button to uncheck the checkbox where I am using Onclick JS,the logic behind the button is define in separate global class of webservice method where I have to get the current  stage name where I clicked.

Comment: Well, I can only think of one thing about null reference error. That is your method (which you try to get tabId) is seperate from visualforce page. (webservice method.) I think you need to put your logic inside apex controller and instead of webservice method it should be inside public method. Or perhaps you can write a public method inside apex controller then this method can call your webservice method passing tabId as a parameter.

Comment: if i want to pass the value of  'ident' variable(Please find the above code)balue to the controller class.How can I pass it? I am very new in VF. when I click on the VF tab its value is stored in 'Ident' variable.I am trying to pass the variable value like this   <apex:actionFunction action="{!StageNme}" name="displayPage">
<apex:param name="v" value="ident" assignTo="{!myCheckbox}" />
</apex:actionFunction> but I am getting null here.Can you please help me how can I pass the value to the controller class?